# Train and deploy model with pre-created Keras architecture in Sagemaker with 'entrypoint'

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, keras, amazon-sagemaker

**Problem preface:**
I have a database of user created neural network architectures (written in a different language that I transcompile to a Keras model) stored in MongoDB. My goal is to take these architectures, create a Keras model with them, then train them in the cloud using SageMaker. As of right now, I can load the models from MongoDB and transcompile them to Keras perfectly fine. *However, I have trouble sending these dynamically created models to SageMaker using the Python SDK.*

Is there a way to train and deploy these Keras model architectures - I.E just Python Keras model objects - in SageMaker by specifying the `entry_point` attribute of an estimator as a file that has these model objects defined?

**Work to Date & Code Example**
As of right now, I can create a training job and deploy an endpoint when the model architecture is defined in a separate file. See this example of the separate file and the deployment/training process on [SageMaker's GitHub.](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_keras_cifar10/tensorflow_keras_CIFAR10.ipynb)

**train-and-deploy-sagemaker.py**

```py
# Import Sagemaker Tensorflow
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

# Create an estimator object using the entry_point file entry_point.py
estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='entry_point.py',
                       role=arn_role,
                       framework_version='1.12.0',
                       hyperparameters={...some hyperparams for the model...},
                       training_steps=1000, 
                       evaluation_steps=100,
                       train_instance_count=4, train_instance_type='ml.p3.8xlarge')

# Start the training job to train the above estimator
estimator.fit(training_data_inputs)

# Deploy said estimator after training
predictor = estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

**entry_point.py**

```py
def keras_model_fn(hyperparameters):
    """keras_model_fn receives hyperparameters from the training job and returns a compiled keras model.
    The model will be transformed into a TensorFlow Estimator before training and it will be saved in a 
    TensorFlow Serving SavedModel at the end of training.

    Args:
        hyperparameters: The hyperparameters passed to the SageMaker TrainingJob that runs your TensorFlow 
                         training script.
    Returns: A compiled Keras model
    """
    model = Sequential()

    ... add layers ...

    return model

def train_input_fn():
    ...

# other functions for inference and training, see link above
```

However, is there a way I could define that architecture dynamically? I.E grab the pre-written architecture from MongoDB then transcompile it into the same `Sequential` Keras model in `entrypoint.py`?

**Potential ideas and concerns:**

1. **Idea:** Just grab the models from MongoDB and do the transcompiling from within the `entry_point` file. Then each method required by AWS can reference the compiled model object.

   **Concern:** Is that secure or best practice given AWS will create a VM from this file to run the code in their cloud? Also the source is later stored in an S3 bucket, so that might pose another security risk regardless of permissions. Also, dependencies like pymongo cannot be loaded from within the `entry_point` file, making the fetching of the data impossible without changing the training image.
2. **Idea:** Do the fetching and transcompiling within the file that creates the training job and deployment instance - `train-and-deploy-sagemaker.py` above. Then pass some code that can reconstruct the model - like Keras model JSON - through the hyperparams attribute within the estimator.

   **Concern:** Hyperparams can only be 256 chars long according to AWS.
3. **Idea:** Dynamically generate the `entry_point` file based on the model architecture it needs to contain.

   **Concern:** Many such as not wanting to create a one-off file on a server for unnecessary I/O reasons, generating code is messy and bad practice, and there has got to be a better way.
4. **Idea:** Make the `entry_point` attribute a non external file and instead specify the required methods within the file where the estimator is created. This would ostensibly solve all of my problems, but ...

   **Concern:** I have seen nothing about this in the SageMaker documentation. Nonetheless, this is the most ideal.

Any help would be appreciated & thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note that to simplify your training script you can use [SageMaker script mode](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-script-mode) instead of the entry_point.py.

1. You specify a requirements_file for your estimator, so you'll have the necessary pip installable libraries. If the MongoDB is running in your VPC, you'll want to run the training job in VPC as well.
2. You can include the relevant files using the source_dir or dependencies params, however they will end up in S3 in any case, you can wipe out the S3 bucket when the job completes. 
   From [class FrameworkModel](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/model.py):

> source_dir (str): Path (absolute or relative) to a directory with any
>   other training
>                   source code dependencies aside from tne entry point file (default: None). Structure within this
>                   directory will be preserved when training on SageMaker.
>                   If the directory points to S3, no code will be uploaded and the S3 location will be used instead.
>
> dependencies (list[str]): A list of paths to directories (absolute or
>   relative) with
>                   any additional libraries that will be exported to the container (default: []).
>                   The library folders will be copied to SageMaker in the same folder where the entrypoint is copied.
>                   If the `source_dir` points to S3, code will be uploaded and the S3 location will be used
>                   instead

3. Yeah, better avoid.
4. Not doable as SageMaker reads code from S3. You could pass an environment

Hope it helps.

Comment: Given that `requirements_file` is no longer supported in script mode, how should I go about including external modules? [Their example](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_tf.html) shows them including a `virtual_env` directory in their dependencies list, but that doesn't seem to work for me as the module is still not recognized. [I also saw a discussion about installing dependencies in the script or using a setup.py](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/556). Should I install in-file, use `setup.py`, or `dependencies`?

Comment: The recommended way is to either use `dependencies` or write a shell script that installs your dependencies before launching your entry script ([example](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-rl-container/blob/master/test/resources/gym/launcher.sh)), but either of those as well as the `setup.py` method should work, so it's mostly up to what you'd find preferable (e.g. if you'd rather not download the external modules to put in your `source_dir`, then maybe writing a shell script would work better).